# Read output in `screen` from outside

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

Suppose I opened up a screen to run some program that outouts some result.

Once the program finishes, is there a way to get the result in the screen from outside.

For example:

1. I opened up a screen using "screen -S myscreen"
2. I detached from the screen
3. The program in screen finishes
4. I want the result in the screen by command like `screen --get-result-from myscreen`

PS:

I am currently deploying a distributed task over several machines.
I need someway to get the result without visiting each screen individually.

#### UPDATE:

Any way to copy part of the content in screen? As there might be other irrelevant information.

Comment: `screen -S myscreen -X hardcopy some-file` would save the content of the screen to a file. You could also use logging.

Comment: What if I want to copy only a part of the useful information? Any way to do that?

Comment: Why not have the process that you're running log itself?  Or if you want only, say, the last 20 lines of output, then `/path/to/myscript.sh arg arg arg | tail -n20 > /path/to/process_log.txt`

Comment: Interactively you can do it by marking part of the screen, copying it to the paste buffer, and then writing this to a file, but there doesn't seem to be a way to script this. Looks like you'll have to write the whole screen to a file, and then edit it from there.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then you will be able to scroll up for the whole screen output.